# Undefined index: userid in

Tags: php

trying to learn php and first project I am attempting is a pm system but I keep getting an error that says Notice: Undefined index: userid in login.php on line 102 &  line 110

hope someone can help i am starting to like php

source code

line 102

```
$nb_new_pm = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select count(*) as nb_new_pm from pm where
((user1="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user1read="no") or
(user2="'.$_SESSION['userid'].'" and user2read="no")) and id2="1"'));
```

line 110

```
<a href="list_pm.php">Your messages(<?php echo $nb_new_pm; ?>)</a> - 
<a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $_SESSION['userid']; ?>">
<?php echo htmlentities($_SESSION['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></a> 
(<a href="login.php">Logout</a>)
```

Comment: Jumping into someone elses code is NOT a good way to learn php, try a decent book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `userid` in the current session. You should first check if it's set using `isset($_SESSION['userid'])`

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you haven't set what $_SESSION['userid'] is equal to?

As a result of this, $nb_new_pm is also undefined, as $_SESSION['userid'] is not defining it.

What exactly are you trying to do with the script?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your ánswer' is what would normally pass as a comment (which, you are not a ble to do until a reputation of 50: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). This is why such answers normally will be deleted on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to PHP's world!

This issue probably is related with the lack of session_start();

When using $_SESSION, you need to **always start the php code with session_start();**.

For example, two files.

**saveinfo.php**

```
<?php

$_SESSION['userid'] = 123;

?>
```

**showinfo.php**

```
<?php
echo 'Hello, we are printing stuff and making calculations';

echo 'You are the user..." . $_SESSION['userid'];

?>
```

Running saveinfo.php and then running showinfo.php won't work. Why? Because you didn't write session_start, that's why.

So, add session_start(); at first!

**saveinfo.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$_SESSION['userid'] = 123;

?>
```

**showinfo.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

echo 'Hello, we are printing stuff and making calculations';

echo 'You are the user..." . $_SESSION['userid'];

?>
```